# Log-normal distribution overtime with initial value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to calculate the expected price and variance of a fictional stock at a time 4 weeks from now. The drift is 0.01 and the sigma is 0.03 (both in years). I've used the formulas below so far.

$$E = e^{\frac{0.01*4}{52}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{0.03*4}{52}}$$ $$Var = E*(e^{\frac{0.03*4}{52}^2}-1)$$
These get me an expectation and variance of approx. 1 and 5.333e-6, respectively. However, the starting price of the stock is €100 so I doubt that that's those are the answers. Have I misunderstood something about log-normals or do I have another step?

Comment: Should I multiply E by 100? If yes then what should I do with the variance? Surely it doesn't vary more simply because the price is higher?